# Google Analytics Traffic Acquisition: Social vs Referral

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We use Google Analytics v4 and I'm confused about the Social and Referral sources in the Traffic Acquisition report.

In the Acquisition -> Traffic Acquisition view, you can clearly see that sources for Facebook are categorised mostly as "Referral" and occasionally as "Social". In my opinion that makes the whole "Social" category pretty pointless if it's not counting all of the traffic from Social media channels. This isn't limited to Facebook, the same is true for twitter and IG too.

[image]

Is this expected behaviour? Is there anything that can be done to better categorise these referrals and social?